# How to inspect playstore apps installed in my android phone on Google chrome browser?

Tags: cordova, google-chrome

How to inspect playstore apps installed in my android phone ob Google chrome browser?

I want to check a cordova hybrid app installed in my phone is making call to which url?

Comment: Open app - > connect device with debugging enabled to pc - > open chrome - > open `chrome://inspect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are inspecting a Cordova app, this can be achieved with Google chrome developer remote debugging. This is the link you should use to get the debugging working properly, but here are some simple instructions incase the link breaks.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Here's a list of simple instructions for Chrome remote debugging:

1. Make sure USB Debugging is enabled in your Android phone's Developer Options.
2. Connect your phone to your development machine via USB, select yes when it prompts you on the device if you're connecting to the computer for the first time.
3. Right click in the browser on development machine, and click inspect. Shortcuts are ctrl+shift+i for windows, or ⌘+shift+c for mac osx.
4. Click the three vertical dots tool menu-->More Tools-->Remote Devices
5. If you're connected correctly, you should see your device under 'Devices'.
6. You can now find your app once you click on your device.
7. Make sure your app is running.
8. Click the inspect button, and a new window will pop up. You can now view the app UI by toggling screencast on, and inspect elements in the view.

NOTE: You must have at least version 4.0 of the Android OS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, tried with chrome inspector for devices via [chrome://inspect/#devices](http://chrome://inspect/#devices), but I found that it inspects only (if I'm not mistaken) web pages opened on device and not installed android applications

I have found the solution by using UI Automator viewer installed by default with Android SDK, it it available on
*C:\Users\[user_name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\uiautomatorviewer.bat*

Once the HMI is opened, click on *Device Screenshot* button:
[image]

When inspecting an app (example of Calculator app under android emulator) The view looks like:

[image]

In Selenium (for example), the click on the button 9 can be performed by:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@resource-id='com.android.calculator2:id/digit_9']")).click();
```